# using absolute path to jest setupFiles

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am using a monorepo, where my modules are stored mostly one level above the project.

In `jest.config.ts`, I am defining setupFiles as:

```
{
   setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/../node_modules/@core/src/setupJest.ts"]
}
```

I would like to use an absolute path since the library directories could change

```
{
   setupFiles: ["@core/src/setupJest.ts"]
}
```

I tried using `roots`, `moduleDirectories`, `modulePaths` to define additional path, but it did not work (this is suggested by a lot of replies to similar questions on S/O, no worked for me).

Does anyone have an idea what else I can do. A bit lost, so will try anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case anyone is interested.

I solved it by:

1. Defining `sec/setupJest.ts` as an “export” (`setupJest`) in the `@core` library’s `package.json`.
2. Using

```
const setupJestFile = require.resolve(‘setupJest’)
```

to resolve
the path to the file.
4. Using `setupJestFile` variable in `setupFiles`